# When a proper morphism of schemes is a closed imbedding?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ and $Y$ be finitely presented schemes over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a proper morphism. Let us assume that for any finitely presented scheme $S$ the induced map
$$Mor_{Sch}(S,X)\to Mor_{Sch}(S,Y)$$
is injective.

**Question.** Is it true that $f$ is a closed imbedding?

The simplest case which I do not understand is the case of $X$ and $Y$ being spectrums of local Artinian rings.

I am also interested in the analogous situation when finitely presented schemes over $\mathbb{C}$ are replaced by complex analytic spaces.

Comment: There is a notion of a closed subfunctor (introduced by Grothendieck), see e.g. [FGA]. Of course $X \to Y$ is a closed embedding if and only if $Mor(-,X)$ is a closed subfunctor in $Mor(-,Y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is true : this is EGA IV, Cor. 18.12.6. (your condition means by definition that $f$ is a monomorphism).

Comment: See also the MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45578/is-a-proper-monomorphism-of-schemes-necessarily-a-closed-immersion where where the same question has been solved, and an easier version (with finite presentation hypothesis) of IV.18.12.6 is referenced.